# How to troubleshoot crashes in malloc

Tags: crash, malloc

I have a large body of legacy code that I inherited. It has worked fine until now. Suddenly at a customer trial that I cannot reproduce inhouse, it crashes in malloc. I think that I need to add instrumentation e.g on top of malloc I have my own malloc that stores some meta information about each malloc e.g. who has made the malloc call. When it crashes, I can then look up the meta information and see what was happening. I had done something similar years ago but cannot recall it now...I am sure people have come up with better ideas. Will be glad to have inputs.

Thanks

Comment: Someone is corrupting the memory (the 'culprit'). The crash site just shows the 'victim'. Aside from using dedicated tools (valgrind etc), you can try this: inspect the memory around crash site (assuming you have the corefile and symbols). Using `gdb`, inspect memory with `x/a <address`, `x/256wa $sp`, `x/s <address>` etc. Look for any recognizable pattern and match that with data elsewhere in the code. If you are lucky, you will trace back to a potential 'culprit' using such data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Is memory allocation broken?

Try [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

## Malloc is still crashing.

Okay, I'm going to have to assume that you mean `SIGSEGV` (segmentation fault) is firing in `malloc`. This is usually caused by **heap corruption**. Heap corruption, that itself does not cause a segmentation fault, is usually the result of an array access outside of the array's bounds. This is usually nowhere near the point where you call `malloc`.

`malloc` stores a small header of information "in front of" the memory block that it returns to you. This information usually contains the size of the block and a pointer to the next block. Needless to say, changing either of these will cause problems. Usually, the next-block pointer is changed to an invalid address, and the next time `malloc` is called, it eventually dereferences the bad pointer and segmentation faults. Or it doesn't and starts interpreting random memory as part of the heap. Eventually its luck runs out.

Note that `free` can have the same thing happen, if the block being released or the free block list is messed up.

How you catch this kind of error depends entirely on how you access the memory that `malloc` returns. A `malloc` of a single `struct` usually isn't a problem; it's `malloc` of arrays that usually gets you. Using a negative (-1 or -2) index will usually give you the  block header for your current block, and indexing past the array end can give you the header of the next block. Both are valid memory locations, so there will be no segmentation fault.

So the first thing to try is range checking. You mention that this appeared at the customer's site; maybe it's because the data set they are working with is much larger, or that the input data is corrupt (e.g. it says to allocate 100 elements and then initializes 101), or they are performing things in a different order (which hides the bug in your in-house testing), or doing something you haven't tested. It's hard to say without more specifics. You should consider writing something to sanity check your input data.

Comment: Thanks.valgrind does not catch the error that we see. Any other inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Try Asan

AddressSanitizer (aka ASan) is a memory error detector for C/C++. It finds:

```
Use after free (dangling pointer dereference)
Heap buffer overflow
Stack buffer overflow
Global buffer overflow
Use after return
Use after scope
Initialization order bugs
Memory leaks
```

Please find the links to know more and how to use it

https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer and 
https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but issues like this will continue to exist as long as we have pointers. Although `valgrind` is the best tool for this purpose, it has a steep learning curve and often the results are too intimidating to understand.

Assuming you are working on some *nux, another tool I can suggest is [`electricfence`](https://elinux.org/Electric_Fence). Quote:

Electric Fence helps you detect two common programming bugs:

```
software that overruns the boundaries of a malloc() memory allocation,
software that touches a memory allocation that has been released by free().
Unlike other malloc() debuggers, Electric Fence will detect read accesses
as well as writes, and it will pinpoint the exact instruction that causes
an error.
```

Usage is amazingly simple. Just link your code with an additional library `lefence`
When you run the application, a corefile will be generated *when memory is corrupted*, instead of when corrupted memory is used.