# Vector out of boundaries access: why such behavior?

Tags: c++, stdvector, undefined-behavior

I am aware that out of boundary access of an `std::vector` in C++ with the `operator[]` results in undefined behavior. So, I should not expect anything meaningful doing that. However, I'm curious about what is actually happening there under the hood.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    {
        std::cerr << "Started\n";
        std::vector<int> v(2);
        std::cerr << "Successfully initialized vector\n";
        v[-1] = 10000;  // Note: if accessing v[3], nothing bad seems to happen
        std::cerr << "Successfully accessed element -1\n";
    }
    std::cerr << "Successfully destructed the vector\n";
}
```

When compiled on GNU/Linux with g++ (GCC) 11.2.0, running this code produces the following output:

```
Started
Successfully initialized vector
Successfully accessed element -1
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why could have that happened? Why does it cause the destructor to fail? Why does it produce such an error message?

I would understand it if I was using some structure that stored the array together with it on the stack: I would then accidentally access some of its internal data that lies right before `v[0]` and could have broken something. But as far as I know, the underlying array of `std::vector` is stored on heap, so the data that I access should not even belong to it, should it? Also, because my last output attempt is taken right after exiting the block with only vector declared in it, I don't see what else except for its destructor could have been called, so the vector seems to be somehow affected by my action...

Comment: Your out-of-bounds access corrupts memory. Sometimes you corrupt memory that nobody was paying attention to (`v[3]`). Sometimes you corrupt memory that the system needs later: `v[-1]` corrupts the memory that the system uses to keep track of the vector's dynamic memory allocations. When the vector destructs, the system tries to free the vector memory, and discovers that the bookkeeping has been corrupted.

Comment: @RaymondChen, thank you for your reply. What is that bookkeeping memory needed for? Is it C++ stdlib or the operating system that you're referring to as "system"?

Comment: "Why could have that happened?" ? You wrote that you already know that it is UB. If yuo want to know whats "happening under the hood" anyhow you need to study the assembly

Comment: Try implementing your own memory allocator. You'll discover that you need memory to keep track of your memory. ([Some discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480655/how-to-troubleshoot-crashes-in-malloc/7480667#7480667).)

Comment: Generally, with STL containers, `[]` can produce strange things when you're borderline. For a `std::map` for example, accessing a non-existent element through `[]` will create and insert an empty element - no way to know if it is was present before with this operator. To get a better error control, prefer to use `at()`, `find()`, etc. because these methods throw exceptions, or return error values, or invalid iterators, but you'll KNOW that something went wrong immediately.

Comment: Learn about the details of the Windows Heap Manager, about its segments, headers, blocks, buckets. And also about pages.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not answerable. UB is Undefined Behaviour. Any answer would have to make assumption about how your compiler, OS, CPU, etc. work.

Comment: @Kolay.Ne - Just to add,  there are cases where the compiler detects that the code couldn't or shouldn't happen, and generates no code whatsoever and whole sections of code just disappear from the final executable.  One such case is doing something like this: `if (this != nullptr) { }`.  That is a nonsense comparison, the compiler detects it's nonsense, and removes all code in that `{ }` block.  So the tests for "what will happen when I do something wrong or write nonsensical code" becomes a fruitless exercise.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, as specified in the question statement, I am running GNU/Linux

Comment: Well, then do some research on the equivalents on Linux: arena headers, bins and chunk headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hypothetical answer that could have happened: The UB caused arbitrary piece of memory to be overwritten. This is called memory corruption.

That overwritten arbitrary piece of memory happened to be right before the dynamic memory that the vector allocated. The arbitrary piece of memory right before the allocation happened to contain an "information header" that describes the allocation. When the destructor was called, there was an attempt to deallocate the memory. The global allocator detected that the corrupted information was inconsistent, produced the diagnostic message and terminated the program.

This is what the source code of the global memory allocator on your system may look like: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#4326 The link leads specifically to the line that produces the error message.